# C# Slow kafka consuming

Tags: c#, .net-core, apache-kafka

I am trying to learn kafka and implement it in my C# API service.

Using Kafka 2.12-2.5.0 on windows server and .Net core 3.1.102

I have my class that implements BackgroundService class like so and all the consuming is in this method that is called by the ExecuteAsync method.

When new message is produced into the topic it gets consumed just fine. Problem is that it will not consume another message in about a 10s window.

If I try to set the offset on earliest it only consumes the first one and repeats every 10 seconds.

What am I doing wrong?

```
private async Task StartConsumer(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    _logger.LogDebug("Kafka consumer starting");
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        using (var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<string, string>(_consumerConfig).Build())
        {
            consumer.Subscribe(_topic);
            var consumeResult = consumer.Consume().Message;
            if (consumeResult.Value != null)
            {
                _logger.LogDebug($"Consumed message: {consumeResult.Value} with key: {consumeResult.Key}");
            }
        }
    }
}

protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    Task.Run(() => StartConsumer(stoppingToken));
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Kafka consumer config:

```
"Consumer": {
  "BootstrapServers": "192.168.1.4:9092",
  "AutoOffsetReset": "earliest",
  "GroupId": "CsharpApp",
  "EnableAutoCommit": "true",
  "EnableAutoOffsetStore": "true",
  "Topic": "myTopic"
}
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more on what you mean with "the first one every 10 seconds"? Does it mean it consumes onlz the one single frst message again and again every 10 seconds?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i figured what the problem was.

I was supposed to have the while inside of the using, not the other way around.